# Move to point in Gazebo environment

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a custom robot model in Gazebo connected with ROS. I want to make it move to point in gazebo environment. I have searched a lot but found only for specific robots, or for real robots, and nothing works. Is there some plugin that would work in my URDF?
Any advice will help!
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17649/move-to-point-in-gazebo-environment/) by [moshimojo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3861/moshimojo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I found the solution in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJ4QPrYqMlw&lc=z23qgtiansydhhhxv04t1aokgy5oh0be1r04r51htgmqbk0h00410.1509998397992193) video. It describes a simple movement to a given point.

---

Originally posted by [moshimojo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3861/moshimojo/) with karma: 11 on 2017-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0